# Not being able to access a SessionScoped Entity in a different Servlet

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I am having the issue, that i can't access a `SessionScoped` entity in two different Servlets. In the `SetServlet` it sets the `SessionScoped` entity correctly and on refreshing the page it is still set. On my `GetServlet` it is always set as null.

Here is my code for the `SetServlet`:

```
@WebServlet("/set")
public class SetServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Inject
    UserService userService;

    @SessionScoped
    UserEntity userEntity;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        userEntity = userService.getUserById(1);
    }
}
```

Here is the code from the GetServlet:

```
@WebServlet("/get")
public class GetServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Inject
    UserService userService;

    @SessionScoped
    UserEntity userEntity;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if(null != userEntity) {
            // do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code from the userService:

```
@RequestScoped
public class UserService {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "unitName")
    EntityManager em;

    @Inject
    UserTransaction tx;

    public UserEntity getUserById(Integer id) {
        TypedQuery<UserEntity> query = em.createQuery("SELECT user from UserEntity user where user.id = :id", UserEntity.class)
            .setParameter("id", youtubeChannelId);
        List<UserEntity> queryResultList = query.getResultList();
        if(queryResultList.size() > 0) {
            return queryResultList.get(0);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry for my bad english.

Any help is appreciated - thanks a lot!

Comment: Why there is no `userEntity` got declared in `GetServlet ` ?

Comment: Sorry i totally forgot to write it in there. I updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two points:

1. `@SessionScoped` does not inject an entity. It just declares the scope the entity injected is bound to. You have to use `@Inject` too.
2. By using the assignment `userEntity = userService.getUserById(1);` you bypass CDI. Your created entity isn't managed this way and cannot be distributed.
   The reason it works twice with the `/set`-Servlet is because the Servlet instance is reused by the EE-container.
   You can solve that problem by just setting the values you want to the injected entity in `/set` like `userEntity.setUser(...)`. But that may cause problems with JPA. The better solution would be using a CDI producer, but then you still need to pass the user's id somehow.

I would not inject an user entity directly at all.
I suggest to write a wrapper class holding the user like

```
@SessionScoped
public class MySessionContext {
    UserEntity userEntity;
    public UserEntity getUserEntity() {return userEntity};
    public void setUserEntity(UserEntity userEntity) {this.userEntity= userEntity};
}
```

You can then inject that class and setting/getting the userEntity to/from there.

You can even inject the build-in [HttpSession](https://docs.jboss.org/seam/3/servlet/latest/reference/en-US/html/injectablerefs.html#injectablerefs.http_session):

```
@Inject
private HttpSession session;
```

There you can get/set the sessions user via `getAttribute`/`setAttribute`-methods.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. You saved my day :-). I marked your answer as correct. I will upvote it, as soon as I have more reputation. I solved it by using the build-in HttpSession.

Comment: No problem :-) HttpSession is propably the easiest way. If you are interested in EE user management/authentication you may want to take a look here: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/partsecurity.htm#GIJRP